# how to Read Write on console from GUI c++

Tags: c++, process, console-application

i am developing a GUI app that will create a child process say cmd.exe and write command to it and read output from it. It looks like this

```
string str;
CreateProcess("cmd.exe"); // child process from GUI
str=writeCmd("dir");      // giving command to cmd.exe and returning output 
cout << str;
str=writeCmd("ctrl+z");
cout << str;
```

if it is possible using using **conin$** and **conout$** please give me an example.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: in this method the i/o HANDLE of child window is owned by GUI, but what if i want to command the same console from std input insted of gui and print it on std out..